# Error when using Photon to build standalone Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app that is doing some data manipulation for some people who have no experience using R. Since this app isn't going to be used by a large amount of people and has some sensitive company data being manipulated by it, I was thinking that storing it locally would be a great option.

I began to do some research and stumbled upon photon. With that being said, I followed the steps found on their github(in their presentation found at this link: https://www.user2019.fr/static/pres/lt257916.pdf).

When attempting to create the app, I am hit with the following warning message:

Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\Users\tylerfrields-re\Desktop\Savings_Allocation_Shiny/electron-quick-start": The system cannot find the file specified

After recieving this message, the commands continue to run all the way to the point of packaging the app, but the app doesn't seem to package. I have all the dependencies installed, so was wondering if anyone could help me resolve the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Quick update: There is now an app there, but the issue is that the app contains nothing. It will run, but it is just a blank white screen. I'm unsure why this is occuring.